# How do I link to a web page inside a WPF menu item?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've found some fairly long-winded ways to do this, but can't believe it's that hard. I want to create a hyperlink to a web page and make that link into a WPF MenuItem.

The hyperlink should ideally open in the default browser. IE would be OK at a pinch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx):

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! Thank you. If nobody else answers in a more WPF-idiomatic way then this will do the trick.

Comment: Even when Url is used in hyperlink you must use Process to actually launch browser so it is "The Way" :)

Comment: This caused a runtime error for me, VS 2022 .NET 7.0. Lunivore's answer below worked great!

Answer (score 1):

To bring Jérémie Bertrand's answer up to date: these days `UseShellExecute` is false by default in .NET, where it used to be true. So now we also need to set that on the `ProcessStartInfo`.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "http://www.google.co.uk";
p.Start();
```